# Trying to create an array and instead creating an array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create an array with information from a json file like so:

```
  var jsonPages = ImportJSON('http://api.etf2l.org/competition/' + competitionId + '/matches.json', '/page/total_pages', 'noHeaders');

  var clan1Id = [];
  var clan1Name= [];
  var clan2Id =[];
  var clan2Name = [];
  var skillLevel = [];
  var week = [];
  var map =[];

  for (var i = 1; i<=jsonPages; ++i) {
    clan1Id = clan1Id.concat(ImportJSON('http://api.etf2l.org/competition/' + competitionId + '/matches/' + i + '.json', '/matches/clan1/id', 'noHeaders'));
    clan1Name = clan1Name.concat(ImportJSON('http://api.etf2l.org/competition/' + competitionId + '/matches/' + i + '.json', '/matches/clan1/name', 'noHeaders'));
    clan2Id = clan2Id.concat(ImportJSON('http://api.etf2l.org/competition/' + competitionId + '/matches/' + i + '.json', '/matches/clan2/id', 'noHeaders'));
    clan2Name = clan2Name.concat(ImportJSON('http://api.etf2l.org/competition/' + competitionId + '/matches/' + i + '.json', '/matches/clan2/name', 'noHeaders'));
    skillLevel = skillLevel.concat(ImportJSON('http://api.etf2l.org/competition/' + competitionId + '/matches/' + i + '.json', '/matches/division/tier', 'noHeaders'));
    week = week.concat(ImportJSON('http://api.etf2l.org/competition/' + competitionId + '/matches/' + i + '.json', '/matches/week', 'noHeaders'));
    map = map.concat(ImportJSON('http://api.etf2l.org/competition/' + competitionId + '/matches/' + i + '.json', '/matches/maps', 'noHeaders'));
  }
  var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  Logger.log(array);
  Logger.log(clan1Id);
```

This is the output I get to the Logs:

```
[17-12-07 04:46:51:235 GMT] [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
[17-12-07 04:46:51:236 GMT] [[23565], [25693], [28116], [18707], [18974], [27513], [27219], [19058], [29798], [23483], [18974], [28078], [29771]]
```

As you can see, this creates an array within an array, how do I fix this?

Comment: Where is `ImportJSON` from? Also, it'd help to have a sample of what the data is being imported.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Jacob ImportJSON is from here: https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs

http://api.etf2l.org/competition/534/matches/1 and 
http://api.etf2l.org/competition/534/matches/2 are the two json files being imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation in `ImportJSON`, it returns a two-dimensional array (which actually means an array of arrays, since JS doesn't have two-dimensional arrays). This is probably meant to mimic the structure of spreadsheet data (rows of columns). Since each of the items in the array you're `concat`ing is itself an array, you'll get that nested structure.

You'll need to flatten. `reduce` can help with that:

```
const importedJSON = ImportJSON(`http://api.etf2l.org/competition/${competitionId}/matches/${i}.json`, '/matches/clan1/id', 'noHeaders');
clan1Id = importedJSON.reduce((result, row) => result.concat(row), clan1Id);
```

...or simply this if you're assuming `ImportJSON` is returning a single row:

```
const url = `http://api.etf2l.org/competition/${competitionId}/matches/${i}.json`;
clan1Id = clan1Id.concat(ImportJSON(url, '/matches/clan1/id', 'noHeaders')[0])
```